# Flutter call Navigator.pop inside async function

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an async function that gets called when a button is pressed.
this function does an http put request, if the result is a success i need to pop to the previous screen.

```
void updateSurv() async{

  http.Response result;
  result = await http.put(
    "http://10.0.2.2:8000/emergencies/${widget.id}/put",
    body: {

      "title" : titleController.text,
      "Content" : contentController.text,

    }
  );

  if(json.decode(result.body)["result"] == "Success"){

    print("success");
    Navigator.of(context).pop();

  }

}
```

The value on the server gets updated, the *print("success")*, but the the app doesn't pop to the previous screen.

so my question is, doesn't the Navigator class work when called from async functions ?

Comment: this also could happen if you used MaterialApp twice, please post the whole code if you can.

Comment: i don't think it is issue of async, may be something else is wrong . can you add more code related to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `.then()` function to execute such operations.

```
updateSurv().then((result) {
  if (json.decode(result.body)["result"] == "Success") {
    print("success");
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
});

Future<dynamic> updateSurv() async {
  try {
    result = await http.put("http://10.0.2.2:8000/emergencies/${widget.id}/put", body: {
      "title": titleController.text,
      "Content": contentController.text,
    });

    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```